# how does twitter bloodhound determine which results to show?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I'm trying to use twitter's typeahead+bloodhound and copying their remote example but am having unusual results.

Here's my typeahead definition:

```
var users = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
     url: host + '/users/search?q=%QUERY',
     wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'users',
  display: 'value',
  source: users
});
```

I have an endpoint that will always return the same json regardless of the `q` query parameter. Here's is what it always returns:

```
[
    {
        "value": "foo"
    },
    {
        "value": "bar"
    },
    {
        "value": "baz"
    }
]
```

If I just type "b" in the typeahead it will fetch the results and only show "foo" and "bar". If I then type in "ba" it will still only show "foo" and "bar". If I type in a letter that none of the options contains, it still returns "foo" and "bar". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: probably searching other metadata which is not returned, which DOES contain `ba`, even if you never see whatever that something is.

Comment: searching non-existent metadata? Is this covered anywhere in the docs?

Comment: not non-existing. non-EXPOSED.

Comment: @MarcB Can you explain what you mean? What other data could this be? The data returned is in the question and doesn't contain anything else?